# Document title with Cyrillic and babel

Tags: titles, babel, cyrillic

I'm writing a document in Russian using `\babel`, and everything in the body of the document seems to work fine. However, when I try to make a Cyrillic title using `\maketitle`, I get errors saying that Russian hasn't been defined, as the title info is placed before the packages are loaded in the preamble.

I'm a bit of a novice so I tried just moving the title info around below `\usepackage{babel}`. This doesn't work either. Is there some way around this? (I'm also open to manually creating a reasonable facsimile of the `\maketitle` environment, within the document body just by centring some large text the way `\maketitle` does, but I don't know how to do this either.)

Here's an example

```
\title{\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
Текст на русском языке
\end{otherlanguage*}}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
Текст на русском языке
\end{otherlanguage*}


\end{document}
```

The title complies, but as nonsense.

Comment: Could you had a minimal working example reproducing your problem for us to help you?

Comment: It seems to me that if you place the title definition just after the `usepackage` command and before the `begin{document}`, it works... The `\documentclass` command has to be the first line of your code.

Comment: If the document is in Russian, why don't you simply drop the `english` option and forget the `otherlanguage*` environment? If you have some English, just exchange the two options, so that Russian becomes the main language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define your `\title` *before* you load `babel` and other packages.  No surprise it does not work.

Just move `\title` after invoking the classes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\title{\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
Текст на русском языке
\end{otherlanguage*}}  

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
Текст на русском языке
\end{otherlanguage*}


\end{document}
```

Also, declarations `\selectlanguage{russian}` and `\selectlanguage{english}` may be more convenient for longer documents than `otherlanguage*` environments.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the title could go anywhere else but a the very top.