# Russian Title with Strange Character Substitutions (in particular, Capitalization)

Tags: titles, cyrillic

I am helping an author typeset his paper in Russian.  Using the `babel` package is mostly working, except with the title.  An example, where the text is "Placeholder title" as translated by Google Translate:

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{Название заполнителя}
\maketitle

Название заполнителя

\end{document}
```

The result is 
[image: a text where the in-body text is fine, but the Title text has strange capitalization]

As a comparison, if I read in the Russian alphabet, with a capitalized А and the rest lowercase (to be exact:`Абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя`), I get:

[image: A title where the first few letters, with the exception of ё, are capitalized, but everything is lowercase after н]

This makes it clear that the issue is the first half of the alphabet (except ё) is forcibly capitalized, regardless of context or position in a word.

It is not the same as [Question 136705](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136705/document-title-with-cyrillic-and-babel), as I'm loading the title after the language rules.

Adding a `\foreignlanguage{russian}{...}` wrapper does nothing, and for some reason, a `\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}...\end{otherlanguage}` wrapper inside the title (starred or unstarred) is causing an error in compilation, as the compiler claims that the command does not exist.

### Question:

> How do I get the title Unicode to display correctly?

**Configuration:** Mac OS X, TeX Live 2018.  (No admin access)

Comment: This may not be your problem at all, but is there a reason you're not using `polyglossia` and `lualatex`?  I've found it makes Unicode problems disappear.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii , the author is trying to submit to a journal.  I'd prefer to keep the exotic TeX tricks down to a minimum.  (Also, I haven't used `lualatex` yet.)

Comment: Makes sense, if the journal author requires `pdflatex`.  But I'd hardly call `lualatex` an "exotic TeX trick".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix this capitalization issue of a macro in the title-command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468245/how-to-fix-this-capitalization-issue-of-a-macro-in-the-title-command) The linked question is not specific about Russian, but the workaround is the same: add `\usepackage{textcase}`.

Comment: @egreg, I agree that `\usepackage{textcase}` solves the issue, which comes from `amsart` (doesn't appear in `article`).  Therefore, I will agree to the duplication.

Comment: @user52733 It's not really clear why the AMS uses `\uppercase` and not `\MakeUppercase`. With `\uppercase{<UTF8 characters>}` one gets random garbage. `:-(`